# Attaching functionality to a button in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button

I have a set of buttons displaying on my webpage. The effect of clicking one of the buttons needs to be that a call is made to an external API (and maybe the response being received, and updating something on the page).

Some additional information: these buttons are placed on the page by a partial, and make up part of a list of users. The buttons are intended to activate and deactivate the users being listed. I'm not sure if this setup will affect the best approach for doing what I want to do, so I thought it would be worth mentioning.

How should this be done? Should the buttons be links to some controller within my rails app? Wouldn't that require the page to be reloaded when the button is hit? Can I offload that request to ajax?, etc.

I don't know the best way to approach this, and any guidance would prove invaluable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I believe I have found a good implementation of this.

The trick is to create a form encapsulating the button in order to hit the proper controller when the button is clicked. In my case, I used the rails `form_tag` function to generate my button within my `_list_item.html.erb` partial view for my Developer controller as follows:

```
<div id=<%= list_item.id %>>
    <%= form_tag "/Developer/toggle", :method => "get", :remote => true do %>
    <p>
        <% if list_item.inactive? %>
        <%= submit_tag "Activate", :name => nil %>
        <input type="hidden" name="act" value="activate" />
        <% else %>
        <%= submit_tag "Deactivate", :name => nil %>
        <input type="hidden" name="act" value="deactivate" />
        <% end %>
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="dev_id" value=<%=list_item.id%> />
    <% end %>
</div>
```

There are 2 things that should be called to attention within this partial.

1. Since this is a partial rendered as part of a list, you want to give each list item a unique id so that your javascript will act on only that element. This is done in the first line, `<div id=<%= list_item.id %>>`, which I know will be unique because each Developer in the list necessarily has a unique id.
2. `:remote => true` is a necessary argument to the `form_for` function this is what causes the request to be made in the background as opposed to loading a new page.

This form, when submitted hits my the `Developer#toggle` action with two parameters: `act`, which is either `activate` or `deactivate` and `id` which is the id of the Developer we are acting on. Both of these parameters are hidden fields within the form.

After the form is submitted, inside of the controller, I just obtain an instance of the correct Developer (in my case, doing so is rather complicated, but in most cases it's probably something like `@dev = Developer.find(id)`), and performs the steps necessary to activate/deactivate the developer.

Lastly, I created a `toggle.js.erb` file within the view directory for my Developer controller which gets rendered once the controller has completed its task. This file simply obtains the element (through the unique id we gave it in the partial) and replaces the inner html by re-rendering the partial as follows:

```
document.getElementById("<%=escape_javascript(@dev.id)%>").innerHTML="<%=escape_javascript(render :partial => 'developer/list_item', :object => @dev) %>";
```

The result is the partial being re-rendered after the developers active status has changed, resulting in the appropriate `Activate` or `Deactivate` button.

I realize that this answer is highly focused on my particular application, especially needing to deal with the toggling of active vs. inactive, however I believe it is easily simplified and adapted to other cases that may require less complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this task with Rails but then page refresh must be done. If you use Javascript/AJAX then page shouldn't be refreshed. Example (jQuery):

```
$(":button").click(function(){ 
  //Your Code here..
});
```

EDIT:
Above is jQuery code. What you want to do is some action to happen when you click on button. If you want to call external API then you could use ajax. Look for documentation for POST and GET in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/.
Google for rails jquery tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It helps me realize that im thinking in the right direction. Could you elaborate a little? How would this be done more specifically? Can the `//your code here` block contain ruby code? Are there any helpful tutorials on this?